# Type trait to obtain default argument promotions

Tags: c++, type-traits, variadic-functions

[Disclaimer: I know an answer to this question. I thought it might be of some general interest.]

**Question:** How can we have a type trait that produces the type that results from performing *default argument promotions*?

**Motivation:** I would like to be able to use variable arguments portably. For example:

```
void foo(char const * fmt, ...);  // Please pass: * unsigned short
                                  //              * bool
                                  //              * char32_t
                                  //              * unsigned char
```

When passing arguments to a function call without parameters, i.e. matching the ellipsis, the arguments undergo default argument promotion. So far so good, but those promotions are platform dependent. I can recover the arguments with `va_arg(ap, T)`, but what is `T`?

Now, for some simple situations this is easy: For example, I can always say:

```
unsigned short n = va_args(ap, unsigned int);
```

The default promotion will result in either a `signed int` or an `unsigned int`, but according to, say, C11 7.16.1.1/3, va-casting to `unsigned int` is always fine, since even if the default promotion results in an `int`, the original value can be represented by both types.

But what type should I cast to when I expect a `char32_t`? C++11 4.5/2 leaves the resulting type wide open. So I would like a trait that lets me write:

```
char32_t c = va_args(ap, default_promote<char32_t>::type);
```

How to do this?

Bonus points for a trait that produces a static assertion when the parameter type must not be passed as a variable argument.

Comment: I was looking to find information about the default promotions, but couldn't find anything that mentioned it is platform-dependent (at least, explicitly). Do you mean that based on the fact that sizeof(int) is platform-dependent?

Comment: @fish: For example, it is platform dependent what the default promotion of `unsigned short` is.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is my solution too complicated? Is there a simpler one?

Comment: @KerrekSB, please post the relevant standard parts when you (or someone else) posts the answer. Thanks for this post, it is very interesting.

Comment: @fish: The standard promotions are described in C++11 4.5, and the connection with variable arguments in 5.2.2/7.

Comment: @KerrekSB user hvd said decltype can be used with operator+(unary), `template <typename T>
struct promote_me_smart {
    using type = decltype(+T());
};` does this actually work?

Comment: @KerrekSB It looks like it does, i have NO idea why, care to explain?

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I'm trying to get it working, but I've already seen it's not as simple as that, that would miss float->double promotion, and it would break for enumerations with a user-provided `operator+`.

Comment: @hvd Kerrek is such a tease.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: Yeah, that's basically it. You probably have to put a couple of specializations in (e.g. to deal with `float`), and maybe use `std::declval`, but unary plus should do most of the heavy lifting. (It certainly works as intended for pointers and function pointers and arrays.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Like I commented earlier, unary + won't work and can't work with enumeration types that provide a custom operator+, unfortunately.

Comment: @hvd: `std::underlying_type` to the rescue?

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, I didn't think of that, that should work. Nice.

Comment: @KerrekSB However, make sure you exclude scoped enumeration types, as they don't get promoted even if the underlying type does.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a skeleton of a solution that works for "most" types (integral, float, unscoped enumeration, arrays, pointers, pointers-to-member, functions, function pointers).

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename U>
struct default_promote
{
    // Support trait for scoped enums

    template <typename E, bool IsEnum>
    struct is_unscoped_enum : std::false_type { };

    template <typename E> struct is_unscoped_enum<E, true>
    : std::is_convertible<E, typename std::underlying_type<E>::type> { };


    // Floating point promotion

    static double test(float);


    // Integral promotions (includes pointers, arrays and functions)

    template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!is_unscoped_enum<T, std::is_enum<T>::value>::value>::type>
    static auto test(T) -> decltype(+ std::declval<T>());

    template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_unscoped_enum<T, std::is_enum<T>::value>::value>::type>
    static auto test(T) -> decltype(+ std::declval<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>());


    // Pointers-to-member (no promotion)

    template <typename T, typename S>
    static auto test(S T::*) -> S T::*;


    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<U>()));
};
```

It does not provide diagnostics for types that cannot safely be passed through an ellipsis. Also, this solution subsumes the decay that types undergo when passed as variable function arguments, so it is not strictly about promotion only.

It works by handling explicitly the pointer-to-member types and the floating point conversion, and by relying on the unary operator `+` for integral and unscoped enumeration types; e.g. C++11 5.3.1/7:

> The operand of the unary `+` operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the result is the value of the argument. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

Some extra work is needed to handle enumerations, since it is possible to overload operators for enumerations (both scoped and unscoped), and so the naive unary plus operator must be used with care. That is, we must consider the promotion of the *underlying type* when the enum is unscoped, and forbid scoped enums entirely.

Comment: :) pretty neat indeed, keep the good questions up, I am tired of answering why someone's array "contains" garbage at the end when they're printing it

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <type_traits>

// Utility type if / else
template <typename T, typename U, bool choose>
struct TifChooseU { };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct TifChooseU <T, U, true> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct TifChooseU <T, U, false> {
    using type = U;
};

// Default - No Promotion
template <typename T>
struct promote_me {
    using type = T;
};

// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast - Let's go in order
// Signed char - int
template <>
struct promote_me <signed char> {
    using type = int;
};

// Signed short - int
template <>
struct promote_me <signed short> {
    using type = int;
};

// Unsigned char - int or unsigned int, dependent on inter-stellar configuration
template <>
struct promote_me <unsigned char> {
    // Doesn't compile without the parens around the operator >
    using type = TifChooseU <int, unsigned int, (sizeof(int) > sizeof(unsigned char))>::type;
};

// Unsigned short - int or unsigned int, dependent on inter-stellar configuration
template <>
struct promote_me <unsigned short> {
    // Doesn't compile without the parens around the operator >
    using type = TifChooseU <int, unsigned int, (sizeof(int) > sizeof(short))>::type;
};

// Char - dispatch to unsigned / signed char
template <>
struct promote_me <char> :
       promote_me <TifChooseU <signed char, unsigned char,
                               std::is_signed<char>::value>::type> {};

// Wchar_t - int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long
// dependent on the amount of goats recently sacrificed
template <>
struct promote_me <wchar_t> {
    using type =
        TifChooseU <
        TifChooseU <int,
            TifChooseU<long, long long, (sizeof(long) > sizeof(wchar_t))>::type,
            (sizeof(int) > sizeof(wchar_t))>::type,
        TifChooseU <unsigned int,
            TifChooseU<unsigned long, unsigned long long, (sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(wchar_t))>::type,
            (sizeof(int) > sizeof(wchar_t))>::type,
        std::is_signed<wchar_t>::value
    >::type;
};

// Char16_t - int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long
// dependent on the amount of goats recently sacrificed
template <>
struct promote_me <char16_t> {
    using type =
        TifChooseU <
        TifChooseU <int,
            TifChooseU<long, long long, (sizeof(long) > sizeof(char16_t))>::type,
            (sizeof(int) > sizeof(char16_t))>::type,
        TifChooseU <unsigned int,
            TifChooseU<unsigned long, unsigned long long, (sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(char16_t))>::type,
            (sizeof(int) > sizeof(char16_t))>::type,
        std::is_signed<char16_t>::value
    >::type;
};

// Char32_t - int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long
// dependent on the amount of goats recently sacrificed
template <>
struct promote_me <char32_t> {
    using type =
        TifChooseU <
        TifChooseU <int,
            TifChooseU<long, long long, (sizeof(long) > sizeof(char32_t))>::type,
            (sizeof(int) > sizeof(char32_t))>::type,
        TifChooseU <unsigned int,
            TifChooseU<unsigned long, unsigned long long, (sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(char32_t))>::type,
            (sizeof(int) > sizeof(char32_t))>::type,
        std::is_signed<char32_t>::value
    >::type;
};

// Enums and Bitfields - maybe later ^^

// Bool - int
template <>
struct promote_me <bool> {
    using type = int;
};

void foo(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    unsigned short a = va_arg(va, promote_me<unsigned short>::type);
    bool           b = va_arg(va, promote_me<bool>::type);
    char32_t       c = va_arg(va, promote_me<char32_t>::type);
    unsigned char  d = va_arg(va, promote_me<unsigned char>::type);
}

int main() {

const char* fmt;
unsigned short a = 1;
bool           b = true;
char32_t       c = 'a';
unsigned char  d = 'c';

foo(fmt, a, b, c, d);

}
```

If there is like a one-liner solution to this, I'll consider a suicide :).
I will probably improve this with `fits<T, U>` template and I'll also fix
the inelegant `wchar_t` and `char16_t` `char32_t` code repetition.

Comment: OK, don't shoot, but I think for C++11 there's something like a three-line solution (if you put braces on new lines).

Comment: @KerrekSB Hahaha, awesome :). Care to post it?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'll leave my answer here to show everyone how big of an idiot I am so your superiority can enlighten the dark seas of ignorance :).

Comment: The checks on `sizeof` are in theory incorrect, you'd have to check `numeric_limits<T>::max()` to use this approach to account for types where not all bits contribute to the value.

Comment: @hvd Mmmmm, I haven't tested this at all, so you might be right here, I'll fix the answer eventually if that's the case :).

Comment: ScarletAmaranth, I started putting together a similar solution, now I'm really interested in the 3-liner by @KerrekSB :)

Comment: @fish I am DYING to know

Comment: I think unary + in combination with `decltype` can be used to test for integral promotions.

Comment: @hvd It seems you're correct, ` template <typename T>
struct promote_me_smart {
    using type = decltype(+T());
}; ` works, as to why, that's an enigma

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: any mathematical expression causes the promotion to occur, and `+var` is an expression...

Comment: @MooingDuck that would explain it :)

Comment: @MooingDuck: See 5.3.1/7 for an even more direct argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be slightly better to avoid `operator+`. `?:` cannot be overloaded, the checks that actually matter can be performed with that as well, and by making the other operand a literal 0, all forms of pointer types get handled properly automatically:

```
// nullptr_t promotes to void *
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value>::type>
void *default_promote_impl(T);

// float promotes to double
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value>::type>
double default_promote_impl(T);

// scalar types other than nullptr_t/float that have a conversion from/to 0 promote to their common type
// this also matches function and array types, after their implicit conversion to a pointer type
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value && !std::is_same<T, float>::value>::type>
decltype(true ? 0 : std::declval<T>()) default_promote_impl(T);

// scoped enumeration types don't get promoted
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>::value, T>::type default_promote_impl(T);

// class types don't get promoted
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value || std::is_union<T>::value>::type>
T default_promote_impl(T);

template <typename T>
constexpr bool check_vararg_passable(...) {
  return true ? true : check_vararg_passable<T>(*(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type *)0);
}

template <typename T, bool = check_vararg_passable<T>()>
struct default_promote {
  typedef decltype(default_promote_impl(std::declval<T>())) type;
};
```

*Update*: passing any type through `...` is valid in *unevaluated* expressions, but in *potentially evaluated* expressions, it's conditionally-supported. The full expression in a `constexpr` function is *potentially evaluated* and can be used to force an error on implementations that don't support passing that type through `...`.

Comment: There is an [`is_null_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_null_pointer) trait :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't know about that, so thanks, but it's not part of C++11, only the upcoming C++14.

Comment: Your solution is strictly for promotion, which is nice; mine includes the decay as part of calling a variable function.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you mean the function/array-to-pointer conversions, that's included in my version too. `default_promote<int[3]>::type` resolves to `int *`. If that's not what you meant, could you give an example?

Comment: What about reference types and function types? `default_promote<const int &>`, `default_promote<int(int,int)>`?

Comment: @KerrekSB They work, and resolve to `int` and `int(*)(int,int)`.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's great then. I think `?:` is nicer than `+`.

Comment: @KerrekSB One thing I found that broke in my version was a class that can convert to/from an integral type (`struct S` with a constructor taking `int` and an `operator int()` was the test I used), fixed by adding a check on `std::is_scalar<T>`.

Comment: Can you check again for unscoped enums? I'm getting a discrepancy, i.e. `default_promote<MyEnum>` is `int`, but `default_promote<underlying_type<MyEnum>>` is `unsigned int`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm seeing what you mean. Given `enum E0 { E0_0 };`, `std::underlying_type<E0>::type` is `unsigned int`. I'll check what's happening.

Comment: @KerrekSB FWIW, if I check with `gcc -fdump-tree-all` for a translation unit that passes an `E0` variable to a `...` variable argument list, the dumps show that it gets converted to `int`, even though that's not the underlying type. I'll check what the standard says too.

Comment: @KerrekSB [conv.prom]p3 "A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration (i.e., the values in the range bmin to bmax as described in 7.2): int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int." I think it's correct, an enumeration with an underlying type of `unsigned int` can still promote to `int`.